# Grouping objects in an array by multiple keys

Tags: javascript, alasql

Initially, I've this array:

```
[{
    "vendorid": 1,
    "vendorname": "Vendor1",
    "maxfilelimit": 2,
    "uploadfilename": "Voice1.xlsx"
},
{
    "vendorid": 1,
    "vendorname": "Vendor1",
    "maxfilelimit": 2,
    "uploadfilename": "Ven1_Voice.xlsx"
},
{
    "vendorid": 2,
    "vendorname": "Vendor2",
    "maxfilelimit": 2,
    "uploadfilename": "Voice2.xlsx"
},
{
    "vendorid": 2,
    "vendorname": "Vendor2",
    "maxfilelimit": 2,
    "uploadfilename": "Ven2_Voice.xlsx"
}]
```

I want the file names in an array with no repetition of records. So, I expect the output similar to following:

```
[{
    "vendorid": 1,
    "vendorname": "Vendor1",
    "maxfilelimit": 2,
    "uploadfilename": ["Voice1.xlsx", "Ven1_Voice.xlsx"]
}, {
    "vendorid": 2,
    "vendorname": "Vendor2",
    "maxfilelimit": 2,
    "uploadfilename": ["Voice2.xlsx", "Ven2_Voice.xlsx"]
}]
```

I found some solutions like d3.js, alaSQL but not getting output as expected

Comment: ```array.reduce``` is your friend.

Comment: thank you! can you please explain how can I use it in my scenario?

Comment: Depends. What changes in your data and what stays the same? When it changes, what's important. I can see you need an array of filenames ... anything else?

Comment: Are you saying that the items should be grouped based on all three of the first three fields being the same? Might be useful to update the example input in the question such that it would have more than one record in the output.

Comment: yeah, you got it right! I'll get no. of records which may contain different `vendors` with multiple file names. So, I want to group the files vendor wise. Where `vendorid`, `vendorname`, `maxfilelimit` are same for a particular vendor.

Comment: sure, to be more specific, I'm updating the question with more records

Comment: `I never did JSON parsing before` - well, `var data = JSON.parse("your JSON string goes here")` - now you don't need to worry about JSON, just plain ol' javascript objects and arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` and inside it you can store your result in an object and then extract values using `Object.values()`.

```js
var data = [{"vendorid": 1,"vendorname": "Vendor1","maxfilelimit": 2,"uploadfilename": "Voice1.xlsx"},{"vendorid": 1,"vendorname": "Vendor1","maxfilelimit": 2,"uploadfilename": "Ven1_Voice.xlsx"},{"vendorid": 2,"vendorname": "Vendor2","maxfilelimit": 2,"uploadfilename": "Voice2.xlsx"},{"vendorid": 2,"vendorname": "Vendor2","maxfilelimit": 2,"uploadfilename": "Ven2_Voice.xlsx"}];

var result = data.reduce((hash, obj) => {
  let key = obj.vendorid+'|' +obj.vendorname+'|' +obj.maxfilelimit;
  if(hash[key])
      hash[key].uploadfilename.push(obj.uploadfilename);
  else {
      hash[key] = obj;
      hash[key].uploadfilename = [obj.uploadfilename];
    }
   return hash; 
},{});
console.log(Object.values(result));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var data = [{
    "vendorid": 1,
    "vendorname": "Vendor1",
    "maxfilelimit": 2,
    "uploadfilename": "Voice1.xlsx"
},
{
    "vendorid": 1,
    "vendorname": "Vendor1",
    "maxfilelimit": 2,
    "uploadfilename": "Ven1_Voice.xlsx"
},
{
    "vendorid": 2,
    "vendorname": "Vendor2",
    "maxfilelimit": 2,
    "uploadfilename": "Voice2.xlsx"
},
{
    "vendorid": 2,
    "vendorname": "Vendor2",
    "maxfilelimit": 2,
    "uploadfilename": "Ven2_Voice.xlsx"
}];
;
// create lookup table
let lookup = data.reduce((p, v) => {
    // seen me yet?
    if (p[v.vendorid]) {
    p[v.vendorid].uploadfilename.push(v.uploadfilename); 
  } else {
    // nope ... first time
    p[v.vendorid] = v;
    // create array of filenames
    p[v.vendorid].uploadfilename = [v.uploadfilename];
  }
  return p;
}, {});

// convert back to array
Object.keys(lookup).map(key => lookup[key]);
```